# How to regress one's Y on a partner's variable X?

Tags: regression, stata

I investigate certain effects within a household / between partners. I have `paneldata` (person-year) for several variables, and a partner id. I would like to regress the outcome of a person on the dependent variable values of its partner. I don't know how to do this specification in Stata.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input float(year id pid y x)
1 1 3  9  2
2 1 3 10  4
3 1 . 11  6
1 2 4 20  2
2 2 4 21  6
3 2 3 22  7
1 3 1 25  5
2 3 1 30 10
3 3 2 35 15
1 4 2 20  4
2 4 2 30  6
3 4 . 40  8
end

* pooled regression
reg y x

* fixed effects regression
xtset year id
xtreg y x, fe
```

I can do pooled and fixed effects regressions. But even for the pooled / simple regression, how can I regress someones outcome on somebody else's independent variable?

Actually for Person 1, I need to regress 9/10/11 on 5/10/. and so on.

- Person 2: regress 20/21/22 on 4/6/15
- Person 3: regress 25/30/35 on 2/4/7
- Person 4: regress 20/30/40 on 2/6/.

**Idea**: If there is no option in the `regress` function, I guess I could create new variables for each independent variable I have and name it `x_partner`. In this example `x_partner` should contain 5,10,.,4,6,15,2,4,7,2,6,. but I still don't know how to achieve this.

```
bysort id (year): egen x_partner = x[pid] // rough idea
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rough idea won't work. `egen` needs one of its own functions specified, and that alone makes the syntax illegal.

But the essence here is to look up the partner's values and put in new variables aligned with each identifier.

Thanks for using `dataex`.

`rangestat` from SSC, a community-contributed command, allows a one-line solution. Consider

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input float(year id pid y x)
1 1 3  9  2
2 1 3 10  4
3 1 . 11  6
1 2 4 20  2
2 2 4 21  6
3 2 3 22  7
1 3 1 25  5
2 3 1 30 10
3 3 2 35 15
1 4 2 20  4
2 4 2 30  6
3 4 . 40  8
end

ssc install rangestat 

rangestat wanted_y=y wanted_x=x if !missing(id, pid), interval(id pid pid) by(year) 

list, sepby(id) 

     +-------------------------------------------------+
     | year   id   pid    y    x   wanted_y   wanted_x |
     |-------------------------------------------------|
  1. |    1    1     3    9    2         25          5 |
  2. |    2    1     3   10    4         30         10 |
  3. |    3    1     .   11    6          .          . |
     |-------------------------------------------------|
  4. |    1    2     4   20    2         20          4 |
  5. |    2    2     4   21    6         30          6 |
  6. |    3    2     3   22    7         35         15 |
     |-------------------------------------------------|
  7. |    1    3     1   25    5          9          2 |
  8. |    2    3     1   30   10         10          4 |
  9. |    3    3     2   35   15         22          7 |
     |-------------------------------------------------|
 10. |    1    4     2   20    4         20          2 |
 11. |    2    4     2   30    6         21          6 |
 12. |    3    4     .   40    8          .          . |
     +-------------------------------------------------+
```